# ASP.Net Core 1.0.0-preview2 infinite redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0

I get infinite redirect loop when I publish application like this:

`/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FLPanel3%2FHome%2FError%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FLPanel3%252FHome%252FError%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FLPanel3%25252FHome%25252FError%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FLPanel3%2525252FHome%2525252FError%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FLPanel3%252525252FHome%...`

But on my Account controller I have [AllowAnonymous] and it doesn't help. My Startup looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true); 

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();

            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator", "Create", "Access", "Manage"));
            options.AddPolicy("Manage", policy => policy.RequireRole("Create", "Access", "Manage"));
            options.AddPolicy("Access", policy => policy.RequireRole("Access"));
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Cookie";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())
            .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings
                .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddScoped<ILPRepository, LPRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<SeedDatabase>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SeedDatabase seeder)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope =     app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Errors/{0}");



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
               );
        });

    }

}
```

I don't have any other libraries that are looking for login, authentication and so on...

Comment: were you able to fix.  I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Check my answer and maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick posting.  Messing around with the anonymous authentication options (on/off) and resetting caches on the browser seems to have my project running ok in FireFox.  However, in IE/Edge I'm still getting the redirect.

Comment: Now for IE/Edge I think that best solution is to Restart you computer. Maybe than it will work :)
For me it works on all browsers after I changed my configuration like this in answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it with Creating new Web Site in IIS and setting my Anonymous Authentication User to "Application Pool" instead of specific user "IUSR" and also setting https on my app.

[image: Change Anonymouse user Authentication]

Now it works finally. And Anonymous Authentication must be enabled. This you can configure on launchSettings.json

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60888/",
  "sslPort": 44444
}},
```

To enable https you need to confiure it also in startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            #if !DEBUG
                    config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            #endif
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

        }).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())
            .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings
                .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
    }
```